# How to prepare sound after reset MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make app like soundboard. Now I have small problem with playing the same sound after reset after playing 1st time.

```
final MediaPlayer SoundOne = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.somesound);
final Button play_SoundOne = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_SoundOne);

play_SoundOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SoundOne.start();

    }
});

SoundOne.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        SoundOne.reset();
    }

});
```

Can I get help how can I prepare that sound to play again after reset (I do reset to make space in memory for next sounds) but SoundOne.prepare() doesn't work if I put that before .start(). Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> It is a programming error to invoke methods such as getCurrentPosition(), getDuration(), getVideoHeight(), getVideoWidth(), setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes), setLooping(boolean), setVolume(float, float), pause(), start(), stop(), seekTo(long, int), prepare() or prepareAsync() in the Idle state for both cases. If any of these methods is called right after a MediaPlayer object is constructed, the user supplied callback method OnErrorListener.onError() won't be called by the internal player engine and the object state remains unchanged; **but if these methods are called right after reset(), the user supplied callback method OnErrorListener.onError() will be invoked by the internal player engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.**

You cannot immediately start() or prepare after reset(). Based on the documentation for reset:

> Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. **After calling this method, you will have to initialize it again by setting the data source and calling prepare()**.

The solution would be

Initialize the MediaPlayer again -> set the Data Source -> call prepare.

Alternatively you can avoid performing reset `onCompletion`. Instead, release the MediaPlayer `onStop()`

You can update your as follows:

```
MediaPlayer soundOne = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    play_SoundOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            soundOne.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(soundOne == null){
         soundOne = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.somesound);
         soundOne.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Don't reset
            }

        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    soundOne.release();
    soundOne = null;
}
```

Comment: So I need to check SoundOne is null? And if it true setdatasource > prepare > and start?

Comment: Whenever you call reset, you have to re-initialize the MediaPlayer again -> set the Data Source -> call prepare

Comment: but if after plays couple sounds (like 5 with different sounds on 5 buttons) I want to click other buttons with sounds but the sound not works. I should immediately make space for next sounds by releaseing resources from the first sounds?
 Sorry for many questions but I'm doing it first time :(

Comment: You can just release the media player whenever its done. When you want to play another sound, re-initialize it again by calling `soundOne = MediaPlayer.create(this, <New resource Id>);`. Just remember to call `release` in `onStop`